# Change backgroundcolor for UIButton IPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I have a problem. I use a Button as a `BarButtonItem`. It works fine so far, but my backgroundcolor works only if I click on my button. How can I make it so that my backgroundcolor will be set every time ?

```
 UIButton *redEmergencyButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
 redEmergencyButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50);

 redEmergencyButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.8 
                                                      green:0.898039215686274509803
                                                       blue:1.0 
                                                      alpha:1.0];    
 [redEmergencyButton setTitle:@"Emergency" 
                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 [redEmergencyButton addTarget:self 
                        action:@selector(doEmergency)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 UIBarButtonItem *rButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
          initWithCustomView:redEmergencyButton];
```

Comment: 5 times bluer than 1! :)

Comment: That's a very specific shade of green right there....

Comment: @Jasarien: That's [229/255](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.898039215686274509803).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line of code for your navigation bar

```
[self.navigationcontroller.navigationbar setTintColor:[UIColor bluecolor]];
```

for button use

navigation button there.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you then provide to other and tick mark this ans and sorry for my letter you can correct it by yourself.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this button instead:

```
UIBarButtonItem* emergencyButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Emergency" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(doEmergency)];
[emergencyButton setTintColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:0.8 
                                                  green:0.898039215686274509803
                                                   blue:1.0 
                                                  alpha:1.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

UIButtonTypeRoundedRect is deprecated in iOS7, Use UIButtonTypeCustom instead for your custom bgColor.

```
UIButton *redEmergencyButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
 redEmergencyButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50);

 redEmergencyButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.8 
                                                      green:0.898039215686274509803
                                                       blue:1.0 
                                                      alpha:1.0];    
 [redEmergencyButton setTitle:@"Emergency" 
                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 [redEmergencyButton addTarget:self 
                        action:@selector(doEmergency)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 UIBarButtonItem *rButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
          initWithCustomView:redEmergencyButton];
```